# how to convert minutes into hours:minutes:seconds?

Tags: php

I have a no. of minute. how to convert minutes into hours.I use following code but it is not working properly.

```
$duration  = "100";
$duration = strtotime($duration." minutes");
echo $duration = date('H:i:s', $duration);
```

`expected output: 01:40:00`

but it gives this output:`15:10:02`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that you try to print out a duration as a date.

Comment: `$hours = floor($duration/60); $minutes = $duration%60; $seconds = 0; echo sprintf("%02s:%02s:%02s", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);` Done. Moving along...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you try to print out a duration as a date. Try this instead:

```
$hours = floor($duration / 60);
$mins = $duration % 60;

echo str_pad($hours, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) , ':' , str_pad($mins, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) , ':00';
```

Comment: `$minutes = $duration % 60;` is better..

Comment: Thd @FDL I added this to my sample code.

Comment: using `str_pad` it gives `10:40:00` without it,it is working

Comment: @DS9 forgot to add a parameter to `str_pad` now it should dispaly correct even with `str_pad`.

Answer (score 0):

Your not giving `strtotime` a full date so it is using your current time as the reference point. If you were to wait a minute and try again it would give you a different result. If for some reason you are set on using strtotime then try this:

```
$duration  = "100";
$duration = strtotime("2000-01-01 00:00:00 +{$duration} minutes");
echo $duration = date('H:i:s', $duration);
```

This is not how I would recommend converting minutes to hours, days, etc... though.